Are complete rewrites the proper procedure?
As one can see from checking the edit history, this question has been almost completely rewritten. This makes all the previous answers and comments either slightly off or responding to points that no longer exist.
I would have thought that the proper procedure for someone who was interested in the issues covered by the question would be to post a new question, possibly linking to the previous question and pointing out how their current question was different.
What's phil.se's preferred action in such a case?

The question should not be completely rewritten, especially not by a third party who may not know the original asker's intention. I have rolled back that edit.

@causative - Thanks. And just to make this question more useful in the future: What's the best way to notify a mod if you see this happen? A meta question like this? Mod contact form? Flagging something? I don't feel like I've been around phil.se long enough to roll back such an edit myself. (I probably don't even have enough rep to have that privilege!)
